# Changing Power Scheme settings through Registry instead of Control Panel in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, registry, controlpanel, control-panel

I'd like to change the settings of a power scheme (say, go to sleep after 45 minutes instead of 30) through the registry, rather than the control panel, in Windows 7. I'd also like to turn hot keys off the same way.

Any suggestions how I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect this would be non-trivial due to the complexity of the power management architecture (schemes etc) & its **always** better to go through an abstracted [API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373170%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) rather than fiddling with the underlying configuration data.

If you dont want to use the API there is the [`powercfg`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748940%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) command line tool.

Comment: Alright, thanks, I think I'll just use the command line tool.

Answer (score 17):

I know this is an old question, but in case anyone has it again in the future, here's an example of code I got to work when I hit a similar issue.

Mind, I agree with the previous assessment of using and abstracted API, but in case this helps anyone:

```
::Set the 'Power Management' to Balanced
powercfg -SETACTIVE 381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e

::Set the unplugged settings to 'Never'
powercfg.exe -change -monitor-timeout-dc 0
powercfg.exe -change -standby-timeout-dc 0
powercfg.exe -change -hibernate-timeout-dc 0

::Set the plugged in settings to 'Never'
powercfg.exe -change -monitor-timeout-ac 0
powercfg.exe -change -standby-timeout-ac 0
powercfg.exe -change -hibernate-timeout-ac 0

::Set the 'Dim Timeout' to Never
powercfg -SETDCVALUEINDEX 381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e 7516b95f-f776-4464-8c53-06167f40cc99 17aaa29b-8b43-4b94-aafe-35f64daaf1ee 0
powercfg -SETACVALUEINDEX 381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e 7516b95f-f776-4464-8c53-06167f40cc99 17aaa29b-8b43-4b94-aafe-35f64daaf1ee 0
```

Source of Reference: http://ss64.com/nt/powercfg.html

Comment: What is `17aaa29b-8b43-4b94-aafe-35f64daaf1ee`? (the very last GUID you include at the end) I see that `7516b95f-f776-4464-8c53-06167f40cc99` (which directly precedes it) is dim timeout -- but I cannot for the life of me find what the former one is either by looking at the docs you linked to, looking at all aliases, or looking at all of the output of powercfg -Q.

Comment: @SoaperGEM

It's been a while, but if I recall correctly `17aaa29b-8b43-4b94-aafe-35f64daaf1ee` is the dim timeout and `7516b95f-f776-4464-8c53-06167f40cc99` is the Subgroup GUID for Display.

Going by that, `381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e 7516b95f-f776-4464-8c53-06167f40cc99 17aaa29b-8b43-4b94-aafe-35f64daaf1ee` reads as such:

Power Plan - Display - Dim Display Setting.

Hopefully that helps clarify!

This appears to support my claim: [link](http://superuser.com/questions/739658/query-current-power-config-settings-on-windows-7)

Answer (score 0):

powercfg /q will list out all the configuration parameters, in addition, for each guid (except the plan) there is an alias.

e.g. powercfg /setacvalueindex 381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e SUB_SLEEP UNATTENDSLEEP 1800

here is an abbreviated output of the /q
  Subgroup GUID: 238c9fa8-0aad-41ed-83f4-97be242c8f20  (Sleep)
    **GUID Alias: SUB_SLEEP**
    Power Setting GUID: 7bc4a2f9-d8fc-4469-b07b-33eb785aaca0  (System unattended sleep timeout)
      **GUID Alias: UNATTENDSLEEP**

Answer (score 0):

look in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\PowerSettings

But I recommend you to use "[PowerSettingsExplorer](https://forums.guru3d.com/threads/windows-power-plan-settings-explorer-utility.416058/)". It has GUI, so it is more intuitive than registry.

Answer (score 0):

You will find the list of schemes at

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\User\PowerSchemes
```

and the active one needs to be registered here with its GUID

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\User\Default
```

Keep in mind that these settings might be overruled by any policy in

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\...
```